# How to make ant not fail if folder on classpath is not found

Tags: ant

I'm trying to modify my ant script so that it will build without error whether or not a local lib folder exists. I want to use the same script on multiple wars, some of which will have WEB-INF/lib, and some of which won't. If the folder exists, include it in the classpath, if not, do not include it. I have tried putting  but I can't figure out where it should go. I think this should be a lot simpler than I'm making it out to be but my Googl Fu is failing me.

```
<property name="local.libs" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" /> 
<path id="local.libs.path">
<fileset dir="${local.libs}" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-path" />
        <classpath refid="local.libs.path" />
                    <classpath refid="server.libs.path" /> <!-- not referenced in snippet -->
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by making the value of local.libs just WebContent/WEB-INF:

```
<property name="local.libs" value="WebContent/WEB-INF" />
```

and then the fileset

```
<fileset dir="${local.libs}" includes="*lib/*.jar" />
```

Then it would build whether or not the lib folder existed.

Comment: The key point here is that the passed-in folder *is* present. The include pattern is more lenient to absent folders (lib in this case).

Unfortunately, this approach does not work for the <src> subelements, since it's mandatory there to have the exact source folder.